# time based trigger not working for add-on users

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers

I have an Google sheet add-on that uses a clock based trigger to make an api call to Google My Business API with a function called uploadPosts().

The User can set the trigger via the addon's menu like this:

```
function createTrigger() {
  try{
    deleteTriggers();
    let ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    let configTab = ss.getSheetByName('CONFIG');
    let hour = configTab.getRange('A3').getValue();
    let hourVal = hour.toString().split(" - ")[0].trim();

    ScriptApp.newTrigger('uploadPosts')
    .timeBased()
    .atHour(hourVal)
    .nearMinute(0)
    .everyDays(1)
    .create();
  }  
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
    if (err.message === "Cannot read property 'getRange' of null"){
      Browser.msgBox(" Woa there! You must run Initial Setup, before turning on Auto-Posting!  ");
    }
  }
}

function deleteTriggers () {
  try{
    var triggers = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
    for (var i = 0; i < triggers.length; i++) {
      ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(triggers[i]);
    }

  }
  catch(err) {
    if (err.message === "Cannot read property 'getRange' of null"){
      Browser.msgBox(" Woa there! You must run Initial Setup, before turning off Auto-Posting!  ");
    }
  }
}
```

The triggers work fine for anyone who is an editor of the Add-on, but does not set a functioning trigger for add-on users.  When they go to https://script.google.com/home/triggers they see a row with a "-" set for both the project name and function name.

[image]

What do I need to change in order for a clock based trigger to work for add-on users?

Comment: What is the value of CONFIG!A3? What value is being assigned to `hourVal`? Does the uploadPost function exists (it was not included in the question)?

Comment: The value is 4 - 5 ( AM ). The hourVal variable then turns that into 4. Yes the upLoadPosts function exists.  It is in a different place in the apps script project.

Comment: The add-on builds the CONFIG sheet for the user as part of initial setup. 

The uploadPosts function is how the add-on uploads posts to the Google My Business api.

Comment: Hello, do the triggers disappear after some time? Or is it immediate? Does this happen with other Add-ons?

Comment: the triggers don't seem to disappear.  I set them yesterday and they are still in place.

Comment: Just a quick note - please avoid comparing against error messages. They might change at any time (for example, Google decides to ditch the current library) - and you will be screwed. In your case you can check that `configTab` is `null` and display the message then. As for the triggers, time-based triggers are a sort of a mess right now, check the [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=time-based%20triggers) and star, comment or start a new issue - your issue does not seem like normal behaviour

Comment: Hello @NoahLearner, do you still experience this issue? If so, could you provide the steps to reproduce it? Are you a G Suite user?

Comment: Steps to reproduce are 1.to create a time based trigger using the docs https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_programmatically using the V* runtime. 2. deploy the add-on to public 3. after google accepts the add-on run the createTrigger function form an add-on menu, look at executions, and project triggers for the project at https://script.google.com/home/triggers and https://script.google.com/home/executions.

Comment: In the stackdriver logs with V8 runtime, when the createTrigger function fires this is shown:

If a non project owner / editor runs the add-on and creates the trigger, the stackdriver logs will show the resource: {
  labels: {
   function_name: ""    
   invocation_type: "custom function"    
   project_id: "gmb-insights-2017-03"    
  } 

whereas with the old runtime that function name is not blank in stackdriver logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this issue was twofold.

1. The project used the newer V8 runtime.  There were tons of issues in the apps script google groups re: the new runtime and time based triggers for add-ons.

I Modified all functions to revert to es5 syntax and then reverted to the old runtime.

2. I needed to add a sensitive scope: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.scriptapp

After I got approved by Google and reverting runtimes, my triggers worked as anticipated.

Comment: Hello, quick question, just adding the scope isn't the fix? Is changing to ES5 a mandatory step?

Comment: Yes. The time based triggers bug is a known bug.  See Here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/150756612